# Parse Field to Select Records

Tags: qgis, query

I wish to select records based on the NRN attribute in my dataset :  `"NRN"  IN ('1','2','23','31')`

Some records have multiple values in the NRN field separated by the underscore character.
For example : `20_21, 14_23` etc

How do I select any records that contain the values that I want ignoring the records that have part of the string but not the whole number? Example : `select 14_23 but not 20_21`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to do this:

```
 regexp_match( "NRN",'(\\b|_)(1|2|23|31)(\\b|_)')
```

This will match either a "1", "2", "23" or "31" which is surrounded by "word boundaries" (
\b") or underscores. (A word boundary is either the start or end of the string, or certain whitespace characters). New numbers to match can be inserted into the "(1|2|23|31)" part - just seperate them with pipe characters.

Edit: if the seperator is a dash, then things are a bit easier (the reason is that dash is considered a word boundary by regular expressions):

```
regexp_match( "NRN",'\\b(1|2|23|31)\\b')
```

Edit: if you're using the expression as a filter, the regexp_match function won't be available. You can use a variation on Anita's answer:

```
 '-' || "NRN" || '-' like '%-21-%'
```

Comment: An error occurred when executing the query.
The data provider said:
OGR[3] error 1: Undefined function 'regexp_match' used.
QGIS version 2.4.0-Chugiak

Comment: Ahh.. That expression wont work in a filter window (since they use the providers native query language, not QGIS' inbuilt one). This expression will work however in the "select by expression" dialog. If you need a filter, use Anita's answer. You may even be able to use '_' || "NRN" || '_' like '%_21_%' to avoid having to modify your data (not sure if that will work with shapefiles/ogr or not)

Comment: I don't want to change the data set. I am in Layer Properties General Query Builder An error occurred when executing the query.
The data provider said:
OGR[3] error 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected $undefined. Occured around :
SELECT * FROM "aus10vgd_l" WHERE  '' || "NRN" || '' like '%_21_%' - The error caret is under the layer name. BTW Quick response.

Comment: Sorry, I am in the "select by expression" dialog now. The separator is a minus not an underscore. I am still having issues with the separator.

Comment: Formatting of my reply got messed up. I've modified my answer with updated code.

Comment: OK - I owe you a beer.

Comment: There are many values that I need and I liked the idea of in a list. How do I extend this to search for all of the values?

Comment: Try the revised regexp i just posted (using the select by expression dialog)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the NRN field from `20_21` to `_20_21_` then you can use `"NRN" LIKE '%_21_%'` to find all features which contain the number 21.